# How can you authenticate additional fields other than username and password?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

On my login page, there are three fields: role, username, and password. Role is a select option where you can choose either client or contractor.

In my DB there a user who is a client.

Say, the user wants to login, but he accidentally chooses a selection to contractor. He presses the login button, but it won't let him because he's not contractor.

How can you achieve this? I tried this:

```
public function initialize()
{
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'loginRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Articles',
            'action' => 'index'
        ],
        'logoutRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Pages',
            'action' => 'display',
            'home'
        ],
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => ['role' => 'role', 'username' => 'username', 'password' => 'password']
            ]
        ]
    ]);
}
```

But it didn't work.

This is my view:

```
<?= $this->Flash->render() ?>
<?= $this->Form->create('User', array('class' => 'login-form')) ?>
<div class="form-group">
<?php
    $array = array('client' => 'Client', 'contractor' => 'Contractor');
    echo $this->Form->input(
        'role',
        array('label' => false, 'options' => $array, 'default' => 'client')
    );

?>

</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <?= $this->Form->input('username', array( 'label' => false, 'placeholder' => 'Username...' )) ?>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <?= $this->Form->input('password', array( 'label' => false, 'placeholder' => 'Password...' )) ?>    
</div>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Sign in!')); ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

This is my controller:

```
  if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user); // hydration
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
                                    // use the layout/login.ctp layout
        $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
    }

    // use the login layout
    $this->viewBuilder()->layout("login");
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to read [this section of the manual](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers) carefully and to the end.

What you do won't work because:

> **`fields` The fields to use to identify** a user by. You can use keys username and password to specify your username and password fields respectively.

Followed by this a few lines down

> **The `userFields` option has been deprecated as of 3.1. Use select() in your custom finder.**

Which should bring you to: **[Customising Find Query](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#customizing-find-query)**

So just implement a custom finder and tell your form auth adapter to use that:

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'finder' => 'auth'
            ]
        ],
    ]);
}
```

Comment: $query
            ->select(['id', 'username', 'password', 'role'])
            ->where(['Users.role' => 'role']);
        return $query;
doesn't seems to work. Where am I doing it wrong

Comment: This appears to attempt to select user records where the role column is set to the string "role". Guessing that's not really what you want?